# Amazon Cloudfront cache issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Hey I have started using Cloudfront. In my application I have images in s3 bucket.
User can update these images .When user update the image ,image get created in the s3bucket and replaces the older image with the new image .After the image get still the older image get dispalyed to user as for GET operations I am using Cloudfront so the older image is retrieved from the cloudfront cache.

So is there any technique to resolve this ...

Answer (score 1):

As is the case with pretty much every CDN, you have to invalidate the cache to get the CDN to start serving the new version. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

I would suggest reading all the content at that link under the "Adding, Removing, or Replacing Objects in a Distribution" section. Actually I would suggest reading all the CloudFront documentation so that you can understand how the service you are using works.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve your issue by setting up your cache TTL to 0.
Go to "AWS Dashboard | S3 | Your bucket | Your file | Edit Properties | Metadata".
There set your "Cache-Control" value to "max-age=0".

More information here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

Comment: But in this case cloudfront will become useless. As the image  will not be fetched from the cloudfront cache it will always be fetched from the s3 bucket no matter user has updated it or not..

Comment: So, you need to find a balance. 0 or any other small walue will allow you to serve dynamic content when bigger TTL will increase your perfromance but you could run into the issue described in the question. As another solution, you could run an invalidation task manually or programmatically any time you update your source object.

Comment: Sure, here is an example about how to do it with python:
https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#CloudFront.Client.create_invalidation